# How to use APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm running Apex 19.2 and I need to generate some pages URLs from some server's scheduled jobs (not from Apex context)

The urls have to have public bookmarks.

I'm using the function :

```
APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=AppAlias:PageAlias:::::MyArg:ArgValue', p_checksum_type => 'PUBLIC_BOOKMARK')
```

from apex context (say from a page) it returns the url with the checksum (which is ok)

but from scheduled jobs, it doesn't generate the Check Sum. It returns a simple URL like :

```
f?p=APPALIAS:PAGEALIAS:::::MyArg:ArgValue
```

Is there any way to generate these urls with checksum from outside Apex context ? like from scheduled job

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

In order to use the function **APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL** a session is required.

So before calling it, a session should be created as follows :

```
apex_session.create_session(p_app_id => 100, p_page_id => 1, p_username => null);
APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(p_url => 'f?p=AppAlias:PageAlias:::::MyArg:ArgValue', p_checksum_type => 'PUBLIC_BOOKMARK')
```

After creating the session APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL will return a URL with CS

Comment: This isn't necessarily solving your problem - those URLs you're generating aren't going to be relevant to anyone's session. Sounds like you need to deep link these URLs?